# How Install Hadoop and Hive in Ubuntu Linux in VM box?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hadoop, package, hive

I am using Windows 7 OS, I would like to learn Hive and Hadoop. So I installed Ubuntu 13.04 version in My VM Box. When i select download the Hadoop and Hive The below URL having multiple files to download Could you please help me out to install Hive in Ubuntu box else Is there any other steps do you have any steps

http://mirror.tcpdiag.net/apache/hadoop/common/hadoop-1.1.2/

```
hadoop-1.1.2-1.i386.rpm       
hadoop-1.1.2-1.i386.rpm.mds   
hadoop-1.1.2-1.x86_64.rpm     
hadoop-1.1.2-1.x86_64.rpm.mds 
hadoop-1.1.2-bin.tar.gz       
hadoop-1.1.2-bin.tar.gz.mds   
hadoop-1.1.2.tar.gz           
hadoop-1.1.2.tar.gz.mds       
hadoop_1.1.2-1_i386.deb       
hadoop_1.1.2-1_i386.deb.mds   
hadoop_1.1.2-1_x86_64.deb     
hadoop_1.1.2-1_x86_64.deb.mds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are new to both Hadoop and Hive, you are better off going ahead with their .tar.gz archives, IMHO. In case things don't go smooth you don't have to do the entire uninstall and reinstall stuff again and again. Just download hadoop-1.1.2.tar.gz, unzip it, keep the unzipped folder at some convenient location and proceed with the configuration. If you want some help regarding configuration you can visit this [post](http://cloudfront.blogspot.in/2012/07/how-to-configure-hadoop.html). I have tried to explain the complete procedure with all the details.

Configuring Hive is quite straightforward. Download the .tar.gz file. unpack it just like you did with Hadoop. Then follow the steps shown [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted).

Answer (score 0):

> **i386**:        Compiled for a 32-bit architecture
>
> **x86_64**:      Compiled for a 64-bit architecture
>
> **.rpm**:        Red Hat Package Manager file
>
> **.deb**:        Debian Package Manager file
>
> **.tar.gz**:     GZipped archive of the source files
>
> **bin.tar.gz**:  GZipped archive of the compiled source files
>
> **.mds**:        Checksum file

A Linux Package Manager is (sort of) like an installer in Windows. It automatically collects the necessary dependencies. If you download the source files you have to link (and/or compile) all the dependencies yourself.

There you're on Ubuntu, which is a Debian Linux distribution, and you don't seem to have much experience in a Linux environment I would recommend you to download the `.deb` file for your architecture. Ubuntu will automatically launch the package manager when you launch the `.deb` file if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 0):

1 .Install Hadoop as [single node cluster setup](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/single_node_setup.html#PseudoDistributed).

2 . Install [hive](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted#GettingStarted-InstallingHivefromaStableRelease) after that.Hive requires Hadoop preinstalled.

Hadoop requires Java 1.6 at least and for single node setup you require SSH installed on your machine.rest of the steps are easy.

Answer (score -1):

goto this link and Download the

http://mirror.tcpdiag.net/apache/hadoop/common/stable/

hadoop-1.1.2.tar.gz  file (59M) from link and Install it...same as if you want install hive then go to offical site and download the stable version from it...